# Error message when opening Googlebase data feed

Tags: google, error

I'm trying to get my site's products uploaded to google's merchant center, but it's only uploading 2 of the ~20,000 I have.  When I open the datafeed url (in Chrome) to look into it I get the error message "error on line 38 at column 761: Entity 'Acirc' not defined
error on line 38 at column 761: Encoding error"  Now I'm not sure exactly what the problem is, when I look at the product where it encountered the error everything looks ok but something is obviously not.  What should I be looking into?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The `&Acirc;` entity represents `Â` in HTML, however, your feed should contain a literal `Â` (with a [supported encoding type](http://www.google.com/support/merchants/bin/answer.py?answer=160079)) instead of the HTML entity.